# Can we make Flutter Engine part of Android ROM?

Tags: android, flutter, android-source

I was wondering if it is possible to add the flutter engine directly into the android ROM (AOSP), so we don't have to ship it with every android app?

I don’t know if it's even needed or what would be the pros and cons of this.
But if it's possible I'd love to do that.

Comment: I think currently a system-wide Flutter engine it would be impractical because Flutter apps are closely tied to the Flutter SDK which is closely tied to the Flutter engine.  It would not be feasible to expect all apps to depend on the same Flutter SDK and engine versions.  A Flutter engine in ROM storage would be even worse since it would quickly be outdated and useless.

Comment: We could have something like exoplayer does, to update the sdk and engine whenever some app with new version is updated in the phone

Comment: You're ignoring the single version problem (a.k.a. [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)).  Without strict API versioning, updating the SDK and engine would end up breaking other Flutter applications.  Maybe that can happen someday, but I think there's currently still enough code churn in the Flutter SDK and engine to make that too much trouble.

Comment: oh okay! but let's say for fun and knowledge if I wanna do this, is it possible to do that if it were for only one flutter application or applications that depend on the same version of flutter?